# Issue when declaring a variable for parameter

Tags: mysql

in my SQL version community-8.0.11.0:

I'm getting an error when declaring the variable in the below code.

```
use `mydb`;
Delimiter //

declare V_id char(30);
set V_id = 'AM-439';
select * from tableA
where TableID= V_id;
    
Delimiter;
```

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: what's the error BTW?

Comment: You should spent some considerations on what the problem yould be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the code in a stored procedure, you can't just declare a variable in a sql script in MySQL.

This seems to work:

```
USE `mydb1`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
declare V_id char(30);
set V_id = 'AM-439';
select * from tableA
where TableID= V_id;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

call `new_procedure`;
```